# Is there any way to center this element to screen?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am starting out using Tailwind with React and I am stuck on this. I tried various methods but still I am stuck. Here is the code and view snippet.

```html
import { Navbar, Welcome, Footer, Services, Transactions } from "./components";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen">
      <div className="h-14 bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-500 to-red-500 border-double rounded-b-3xl border-b-8 w-5/6">
        <Welcome />
      </div>
      <div className="h-14 bg-gradient-to-b from-blue-500 to-green-500 rounded-lg w-1/2 flex justify-center ">
      <Services />
      </div>
      <Transactions />
      <Footer /> 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try adding `mx-auto` class to your gradient divs? If that doesn't work you could also try `text-center` in your main div.